# Firebase one to one chat security rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

From numerous other posts, it seems that the recommendation for creating the structure for one to one chat seems to be to combine two user IDs, taking into account their natural ordering.  For example:

```
root{
    messages:{
        user1_user2:{
            //messages here
        },
        user1_user3:{
            //messages here
        }
    }
}
```

Seems fine and is much more efficient than creating a personal message topic for each user.  So my question now is what would be the best way to secure this?  Right now I have the following:

```
"messages":{
      "$channel":{
        ".read": "$channel.beginsWith(auth.uid) || $channel.endsWith(auth.uid)"
      }
    }
```

Is this sufficient? Can't shake the thought that it's possible for a different but longer user id that starts or ends the same way will get past this check

Comment: I would not secure based on substring detection, unless there is no other option. In this case there *is* another option: keeping an explicit list of the room's members. `root: { room_members: { user1_user2: { user1: true, user2: true }}}`

Comment: Hmmm, and how will this node be secured?  Sorry, still trying to wrap my head around the security rules framework.  Currently reading the docs to see if I'm missing anything, but is something like validate: newData.chile(auth.uid) == true the right approach?

Comment: Your current rule would instead check `root.child('room_members').child($channel).child(auth.uid).exists()`

Comment: Ah yes, understood that part.  Sorry was editing a previous comment, but my follow up to that would be how now to secure the room_members node so that the list of members can't changed be just by any other user

Comment: Ignore the fact for a moment that the $channel consists of the two uids. Just think of it as a random string for now. In that scenario the members in the room are whoever you put in to `/room_members/$channel` when you first create it. So it's not a problem. The fact that you use the two uids to generate the room name is just to allow consistent lookup, it has nothing to do with security.